# Single Element Java Data Structures that overwrite

Tags: java, data-structures

I've been using `TreeMap<String,Object>` to store objects as they don't allow entries with duplicate keys,

Is there a a similar data structure that only takes in a value/key and doesn't allow duplicate entries?

so something like `Type<String>` where all the Strings have to be different (or they overwrite)

until now ive just been using `Vector<String>` with checks to see if an entry is already in the vector before adding it which is a bit messy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is what you are looking for. There are couple of implementations of this interface. The most common is the HashSet (fast `contains()` operation but the order is not guaranteed), [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (this is actually implementation of [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), the instances stored in [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) should implement `Comparable`) and the last commonly used is the [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). The order of [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) is derived from the time elements were added into the container.

Recently, I saw this handy diagram: [image: diagram]

Comment: I wish I had seen that before!

Comment: The image is good but lacks the explanation of `LinkedList` and `Deque` class implementations, but is good.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a [`Set<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), more specifically a [`TreeSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Also, please don't use `Vector`, instead use `List` backed by an `ArrayList`. Refer to:

- [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197)
- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and the equivalent to what you propose is [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). However I think [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) will do better job for the task you describe.